# How to hide/show a LinearLayout by scrolling the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Fragment with a Layout that shows two TextViews and bellow, Cards in a ListView, according the feed_fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.maik.projphotocrowd.YourPhotosFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/all_photos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All photos"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/just_your_photos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My photos"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_firebase_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The screen is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvV6V.png)

I want to hide the LinearLayout that contains the TextViews when scroll the screen down and show it again when scroll up using an animation. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well we will use **Parallax Effect** for this

First create a header layout file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/stickyViewPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second let's handle the list scrolling

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
textContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.textContainer);

// Inflate list header layout 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View listHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
stickyViewSpacer = listHeader.findViewById(R.id.stickyViewPlaceholder);

// Add list view header 
listView.addHeaderView(listHeader);

//Handle list View scroll events 
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        // Check if the first item is already reached to top/
        if (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
            View firstChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
            int topY = 0;
            if (firstChild != null) {
                topY = firstChild.getTop();
            }
            textContainer.setY(topY * 0.5f);
        }
    }
});
```